# ManagedPipeLineHandler generates 400 on Document Upload

Tags: asp.net, iis

i have been trying to upload a PDF document and facing 400 bad request issues. Surprising this is working on another machine but not the production machine

After enabling Failed Request Tracing
[image]

ManagedPipeLineHandler generates 400 bad request. but I can't find any clue why it is, I have already checked maxRequestLength and maxAllowedContentLength.

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" maxRequestLength="1048576"  />
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1048576000" />
```

apparently, nothing much is wrong . from failed request its quite clear IIS has received document bytes and then generate an error

any advice or help will surely be appreciated.

Comment: Can you make sure the issue is from IIS? You mentioned that it's ok in another machine, so when you test in that machine, did you use the same configuration and the same pdf file? I think we should first rule out the possibility of the application and the file itself. Then we can consider the runtime or environment.

Comment: Yes, this is from iis as per Failed request tracing. the application did not receive request and this is only happening with file upload handler other than that every thing in the application is working fine

Comment: Please allow me to share some link first. [http status code for IIS troubleshooting] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/http-status-code#4xx---client-error) and [a 400 scenario in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/http-bad-request-response-kerberos). Normally we should check IIS log first but since you mentioned that `the application did not receive request`, so it seems you have no need to review the IIS log. Then we may use fiddler to capture traces for the request.

Comment: Then you can check the 400 response and in particular “Server” variable – if it has the value MS HTTPAPI/2.0 it means the response was generated by HTTP.SYS, If the failure status is generated by HTTP.SYS, collect and examine HTTPERR.log file. The file is normally stored in c:\windows\system32\LogFiles\HTTPERR folder. Then check if there's any useful information on it.

Comment: Thanks i will look into the details and will update